# Swapping int with string using getchar() and putchar()

Tags: c, array, pointers

I wrote code that replaces integers from 0 to 3 with strings. I was only allowed to use `getchar()` and `putchar()`. If the input is 1, the output will become "one".

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{


int c;            

char* arr[4] = {"zero", "one", "two","three"};

int i;

  while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF) 
    {

        if(c==0+'0'){
        char* str = arr[0];
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {

    putchar(str[i]);

}
}


else if(c==1+'0'){
char* str = arr[1];
      for (i= 0; str[i] != '\0';i++) {

    putchar(str[i]);


}
}

else if(c==2+'0'){
char* str = arr[2];
      for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        putchar(str[i]);

}
}
else if(c==3+'0'){

    char* str = arr[3];
     for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    putchar(str[i]);

}   
}



        else
        putchar(c);

   }

return 0;


}
```

The code is pretty long. Is there a shorter way to write it?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle all the cases for 0 to 3 in a single piece of code. There basic idea is:

> If the character is between 0 and 3, print the corresponding word, otherwise print only the character.

In C code, this reads:

```
if ('0' <= c && c <= '3') {
    const char *word = arr[c - '0'];
    while (*word != '\0') {
        putchar(*word);
        word++;
    }
} else {
    putchar(c);
}
```

With this code, it is much simpler to extend the list of words for the remaining digits. Instead of copying and adjusting a whole block of code, you only have to change the code at two places:

- The array of the actual words, adding `"four"`
- The `'3'` in the `if` clause

This can even be reduced more:

```
if ('0' <= c && c <= '0' + sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]) {
```

After this change you only need to add the words to the array. Everything regarding `sizeof` is fairly advanced stuff though, so I don't expect you to fully understand this right now. But it's good to know that there is a way, at least.

By the way, this code does not swap anything. It is better to call this "replace" instead of "swap". As a programmer, you should be as precise as possible.

Comment: Thank you. I want to get better at programming and I will take your advice to be more precise while asking questions.

Answer (score 4):

### Review

#### Vertical White Space

You have way too many blank lines.
Please remove 90% of them.

#### Formatting

This code is horribly formatted.
Code is designed for humans to read. Part of that is making sure it is easy to read.

#### DRY

There is one piece of code that is repeated several times.

```
for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    putchar(str[i]);
}
```

You can simplify your code by putting this into its own function. Then calling the function when you want to print out the string.

#### Easier to read

Your comparisons to check for a number is overly complex:

```
else if(c==2+'0'){
```

The `c` is a character so simply compare the user input to the expected character:

```
 else if (c == '2') {
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Roland's review](/a/194194), I'd like to mention good use of `const`.

We have:

```
char* arr[4] = {"zero", "one", "two","three"};
```

Since we never modify the strings in this array¹, we can go further and make the elements pointers to **`const`** `char`:

```
const char *arr[4] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three"};
```

Further, we don't want to modify the pointers themselves (assuming we don't plan to make this program multi-lingual), we can declare them as **`const`** pointers to `const char`:

```
const char *const arr[4] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three"};
```

As a further refinement, we can make this **`static`**, which means the array can be stored in read-only memory (like a global constant), rather than within the stack-frame of `main()`:

```
static const char *const arr[4] = { "zero", "one", "two", "three" };
```

I know it looks a bit heavy when expressed like that, but once you understand each word in the declaration, it's very precise!

---

¹ In fact, we *mustn't* modify the strings, because a string literal such as `"zero"` is a *constant* object; the ability to assign a string literal to a plain `char*` variable is a historical - and undesirable - artefact of C (it dates from before the `const` keyword was added to the language more than 30 years ago).  GCC has an option, `-Wwrite-strings`, to alert you to code that uses this feature, so you can add the necessary `const` - I recommend you use it, in addition to `-Wall -Wextra`, and heed its output.